# Java: How to read multiple inputs from scanner that are separated by a space and commas and store them in variable?

Tags: java

Let's say I am trying to add to a grocery list, and the following is what would be my single line input: (add Apple, Fruit, 10, 5.67). How would I parse the values from the Scanner to separate the list and have it stop reading values after I hit enter?

Would this be the right format to separate the list?

```
Scanner list = new Scanner (System.in);
list.useDelimiter(["\\s | ,\\s"]);
```

Comment: What happens when you test your code?

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you expect your code to work exactly? Can you add some description of how you want to provide and handle such input? Also does your input really start and ends with parenthesis?

Comment: It only takes in the first 2 values, add and Apple. Waits for more input and then exits the program. I'm using case statements, depending on if the first input is add, remove or search. So for example, if it's add it should jump to the add case and parse the inputs from the list and store it in the object created. It's only able to store Apple and ignores the rest of the inputs when I use list.next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading the whole line then using String.split as in

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {

        String str = input.nextLine();  // Apple, Fruit, 10, 5.67

        String arr[] = str.split (", ");

        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

**Result**

```
Apple
Fruit
10
5.67
```

Comment: But what if the input depends on the user? So if the fruit, type, quantity and price are unknown before hand?